# Create user - map network drive CMD

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, windows-command-prompt, mapping

I have a pipeline which I want to do automatically (probably with a bat file) without the need to do all steps manually on my windows 10 machine.

Pipeline steps:

1. Create a normal user account e.g userA. I know this can be done using this `net user userA passuserA /add`
2. Map network drive using cmd, I know this can be done using `net use * \\myshared\directory /u:domainname\domuserA password` but I wonder if this will work without being logged in the machine? which brings me to my question is there a way Login to the computer using userA remotely once it's created then mount the drive to the user. My goal is that to put all this in a batch file and run it so that I don't have to repeat these steps but I am not sure how it can be done?

Comment: you can configure login script for userA for auto mount

Comment: @batistuta09 Can you tell me how?

Comment: https://www.websense.com/content/support/library/web/v78/logon_agent/la_configure_scripts.aspx